# Angular - multiple subscribe using IIF

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to make a change in an existing application , so in the ngOnInit , I should call a service to get "typeIndividu" , so according to this paremeter I will make another HTTP call .
I found that it's not recommended to use a subscribe inside another subscribe and we should use mergeMap but I don't find the way to do that

**tableau-de-bord.component.ts**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.listeDesReclamationsChargeesDepuisCobol = [];
    this.listeDesReclamationsAffichees = [];

    this.individuService.recupererLeTypeDeLIndividu().subscribe(
        (typeIndividu: TypeIndividu) => {
            this.logger.debug(`[${this.constructor.name}] - Recuperer le type de l'individu : `, typeIndividu);
            this.typeIndividu = typeIndividu;
            if (this.typeIndividu.codeType == TYPE_INDIVIDU_DE) {
                this.getListeReclamationsDE();
            }else{
                this.getListeReclamationsReclamant();
            }
        },
        error =>
            this.logger.error(`[${this.constructor.name}]  - Erreur lors de la récupération du type de l'individu`, error)
    );  
}

  getListeReclamationsReclamant(){
    this.reclamationService.lireListeReclamations().subscribe(
        (response: ListeReclamationsCobol) => {
            this.infosServiceCobolListeReclamations = response;
            this.listeDesReclamationsChargeesDepuisCobol = response.listeReclamations;
            this.listeDesReclamationsAffichees = new Array<Reclamation>();
            this.afficherPlusDeReclamations();
        },
        error =>
            this.logger.error(
                `[${this.constructor.name}]  - Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste des réclamation dans Aude`,
                error
            )
    );
}

getListeReclamationsDE(){
    this.reclamationService.getListeReclamation().subscribe(
        (res: ReclamationVisualisation[]) => {
            this.reclamationsVisualisation = res;
            this.mappingReclamation();
            this.listeDesReclamationsAffichees = new Array<Reclamation>();
            this.obtenirLesNReclamationsSuivantes();
        },
        error =>
            this.logger.error(
                `[${this.constructor.name}]  - Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste des réclamations`,
                error
            )
    )
}
```

and this are the Services :

**individu.service.ts**

```
   recupererLeTypeDeLIndividu(): Observable<TypeIndividu> {
    this.logger.debug(`[${this.constructor.name}] - service de récupération du type de l'individu`);
    return this.httpClient
        .get<TypeIndividu>(`${this.urlFacadeApi}${this.resourceType}`)
        .pipe(tap((typeIndividu: TypeIndividu) => (this.donneesTypeIndividuCache = typeIndividu)));
   }
```

**reclamation.service.ts**

```
   public getListeReclamation(): Observable<ReclamationVisualisation[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ReclamationVisualisation[]>("./assets/reclamations.json");
}


  lireListeReclamations(): Observable<ListeReclamationsCobol> {
    this.logger.debug(`[${this.constructor.name}]- service de récupération de la liste des 
   réclamations`);

    return this.httpClient.get<ListeReclamationsCobol> 
   (`${this.urlFacadeApi}${this.resourceReclamation}`);
   }
```

I can't find the way to use mergeMap with IIF .

Answer (score 0):

you should just use it like this

```
this.individuService.recupererLeTypeDeLIndividu().pipe(
    mergeMap((typeIndividu: TypeIndividu) => {
        if (typeIndividu.codeType == TYPE_INDIVIDU_DE) {
            return this.getListeReclamationsDE();
        } else {
            return this.getListeReclamationsReclamant();
        }
    }
    ).subscribe(here you have the result of functions that are being returned by if-else )
```

and your methods should return observables instead of subscriptions: add return to the functions and don't use subscribe on them)

All the additional logic you can move to subscribe above, or use tap operator in pipes, where it's needed

Comment: But in the subscribe how I will know which functions is called so I can initialize the parameters of this functions .For example if  **getListeReclamationsReclamant**  is called so I have to do this : `this.infosServiceCobolListeReclamations = response;
            this.listeDesReclamationsChargeesDepuisCobol = response.listeReclamations;
            this.listeDesReclamationsAffichees = new Array<Reclamation>();
            this.afficherPlusDeReclamations();`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) since you're not using anything from the first response to pass along to the second request.

```js
this.individuService.recupererLeTypeDeLIndividu()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((typeIndividu: TypeIndividu) => {
      this.logger.debug(`[${this.constructor.name}] - Recuperer le type de l'individu : `, typeIndividu);
      this.typeIndividu = typeIndividu;
      const isTargetType = this.typeIndividu.codeType === TYPE_INDIVIDU_DE;
      return isTargetType ? this.getListeReclamationsDE() : this.getListeReclamationsReclamant();
    }),
  )
  .subscribe((value: any) => {
      // Handle response here...
      console.log(value);
    },
    error => this.logger.error(`[${this.constructor.name}]  - Erreur lors de la récupération du type de l'individu`, error)
  );
```

Comment: So how I can initialize the parameters that exist in the subscribe of the two methods **getListeReclamationsReclamant** and **getListeReclamationsDE**

Comment: @alaabourouissi ill update, but basically in the subscription just define some arbitrary name that represents the values returned from that request.

Answer (score 0):

Chain these requests, like already suggested by others. You can do it with `switchMap` (or `mergeMap`). Then based on the condition call one of the two functions. Those two functions should not have subscribe in them, instead return an observable from those.

So

```
this.individuService.recupererLeTypeDeLIndividu()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((typeIndividu: TypeIndividu) => {
      this.typeIndividu = typeIndividu;
      return this.typeIndividu.codeType === TYPE_INDIVIDU_DE ?
        this.getListeReclamationsDE() : 
        this.getListeReclamationsReclamant();
    }),
  )
  .subscribe((value: string) => {
      // here you get the response of one of the called functions
      // and we are just returning a string from there, return
      // something you feel is appropriate
  });
```

and then the two functions (shortened):

```
getListeReclamationsReclamant(){
  this.reclamationService.lireListeReclamations().pipe(
    map((response: ListeReclamationsCobol) => {
      this.infosServiceCobolListeReclamations = response;
      // do more stuff and return something of your choosing...
      // here just an example
      return 'getListeReclamationsReclamant called!'
    })
  )
}

getListeReclamationsDE(){
  this.reclamationService.getListeReclamation().pipe(
    map((res: ReclamationVisualisation[]) => {
      this.reclamationsVisualisation = res;
      // do more stuff and return something of your choosing...
      // here just an example
      return 'getListeReclamationsDE called!'
    })
  )
}
```